# What does the following command do ls -la | sort | wc -l

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When I run this command in terminal it displays a number.
The number changes when I mount another folder using cd command.

Comment: Thanks for your help !

Comment: [explainshell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ls+-la+%7C+sort+%7C+wc+-l) to the rescue!

Comment: take the cmd one step at a time. What does `ls -la` (in a small directory) do? Now add the `|sort` How has it changed. Now add `|wc -l` Oh.. way different right? Composing cmd chains and decomposing them (for debugging)is a major key (and beauty) of Unix/Linux shell scripting. Small programs that do one thing well and can be connected together with pipes (`|`). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls -la // List files in your current directory (hidden files are included thanks to the -a)

sort // Sort entries returned by the previous command

wc -l // Returns the number of lines returned by the previous command
```

«|» send the output of one command to the input of the next one